# PHP Range function for creating steps between 2 dates

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a range of dates between 2 dates, but the max amount of steps is 10. I tried using the `range()` function but that only works for alphabetical and numeric steps as far as I figured out.

So for example I have a date `03/07/2018` and a date `23/04/2015`, I'd like to get 10 steps in between from the start till the end.

Simple example would be `01/01/2018` till `01/12/2018` you'd get start and end steps + the 10 steps added (`01/02/2018, 01/03/2018`) etc. And ofcourse if you have less then 10 steps (days) in between, create less steps.

What I have now is:

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2012-08-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2012-08-31' ); 

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
}
```

But instead of having the `P1D` interval for `DateInterval()`, I want it to be 10 steps.

Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: `range` won't help you a lot there, no. No pre-existing function can really help you, since it's extremely ambiguous what the behaviour should be if you're starting at Jan. 31st for example and want to add a month to it.

Comment: *"create a range of dates"* -- this is what the [`DatePeriod` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) does for a living. However, please notice that *"one month"* is a time interval that spans between 28 and 31 days, depending on who and about what month you ask.

Comment: @deceze I kinda figured out that there is no specific pre-existing function that can do it. But i was hoping someone could help me out with a function to do so.

Comment: @axiac That's why the span of the steps should be calculated with a max of 10 steps. Is that possible with DatePeriod? I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this: https://www.rarst.net/code/php-date-range/

Comment: @MrJ. Yea I read that, but that function asks you to add steps of for example +1 day, I want my steps to be calculated on the go, as I want 10 steps between whatever date I fill in. For example if I fill in 10 years in between, each step will be 1 year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try following code to find 10 intervals between given dates:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2012-08-01');
$end = new DateTime('2012-08-31');

$x = $end->diff($begin);
$intervalDays = ceil($x->days / 10);
$interval = new DateInterval('P' . $intervalDays . 'D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    echo $date->format("Y/m/d") . "<br>";
}
```

Your code is almost near to the solution and a little effort make it as you required.

Comment: Thanks, that'll work perfect with the rest of use. Solution found :D

Answer (score 1):

Get the amout of days inbetween the start and end date like [here](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php). Then divide the amount by n. Then loop i=1 to n and add the result to the start-date every time you run through the loop ([Datetime::modify](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.modify.php)). Cache the results in an array. Done.